# Data Would not Display on Reportviewer

Tags: c#

I am trying to make something like a Bank Statement Application but i have a problem along the line.

Now it gets the datasource and all , but doesnt get the values from the Database and display on a report viewer. Apparently i am missing something , Hence i decided to bring it on here

Code Looks like this:

```
namespace TmpZ
{
    public partial class BalanceSheet : Form
    {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnData"].ConnectionString;
        public BalanceSheet()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (accountNo1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Account Number");
            }
            else
            {
                DataTable dtb = new DataTable();
                dtb = GenerateBankStatement(dtb);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportDataSource rpd = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dtb);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rpd);
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
        }

        private DataTable GenerateBankStatement(DataTable dt)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [id] as id, [transaction_desc] as transaction_desc,[credit] as credit, [debit] as debit, [balance] as balance, [transaction_date] as transaction_date FROM transactions WHERE(accountNo1 = '" + accountNo1.Text + "') AND(transaction_date BETWEEN '" + dateFrom.Text + "' AND '" + dateTo.Text + "')", cn);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing? it shows empty data on Boxes in reportviewer.

Comment: Lets verify the datatable has data.  So put break point (F9) on the statement  : return dt;  Then over over the variable dt and press with mouse the down arrow and then click on Data Visualizer.  See if you see data.  If there is not data then your query is wrong.

Comment: @jdweng i use it inside the MSSQL management studio i see whatever i am looking for hence i used in Visual studio

Comment: i changed the Query, everything is the same , no changes

Comment: Using the Data Visualizer is much simpler than the steps you took.  It would of taken only a couple of minutes to put the break point and looks at the Data Visualizer.  It would of told you the query was correct.

Comment: This is not a sql-server question. please use tags properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i finally fixed it. It was an issue with the Date Formatting. I had to make them strings and the code Works Fine at this point. Code now looks like this for those that want to work on something like this Much later

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

namespace TwpZ
{
    public partial class BalanceSheet : Form
    {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnData"].ConnectionString;
        public BalanceSheet()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BalanceSheet_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (accountNo1.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Account Number");
            }
            else
            {
                DataTable dtb = new DataTable();
                dtb = GenerateBankStatement(dtb);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportDataSource rpd = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dtb);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rpd);
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
        }

        private DataTable GenerateBankStatement(DataTable dt)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                try
                {
                    string dateF = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFrom.Text).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    string dateT = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTo.Text).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [id] as id, [transaction_desc] as transaction_desc,[credit] as credit, [debit] as debit, [balance] as balance, [transaction_date] as transaction_date FROM transactions WHERE(accountNo1 = '" + accountNo1.Text + "') AND(transaction_date BETWEEN '" + dateF + "' AND '" + dateT + "')", cn);
                    //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [id] as id, [transaction_desc] as transaction_desc,[credit] as credit, [debit] as debit, [balance] as balance, [transaction_date] as transaction_date FROM transactions WHERE(accountNo1 = '" + accountNo1.Text + "')", cn);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```